# Properly Utilizing Epoch Seconds with JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I would like to store all of the dates in my database as epoch seconds in order to eliminate timezone ambiguity. I am using the [`JpaRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) interface provided through one of Spring Boot's starters (Data for JPA) to persist changes that I make to the entities that will store epoch seconds. However, I am having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to keep everything updated properly.

For example, I have one table that has a `Created`column and a `Modified`column. As may be obvious, I need the `Created` column to be provided with epoch seconds for each new entry that is added, and I need the `Modified` column to be updated every time that an existing entry is changed.

Can I accomplish this using a combination of MySQL defaults in my table design and annotations with my JPA entities, or do I need to implement a `Repository` that takes care of this creation/updating for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply store the millis in a NUMERIC column while having the OOP side operate on Date objects:

```
public class MyEntity {

    @Column
    private long createdOn;

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return new Date(createdOn);
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn.getTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to store everything still as epoch seconds, converting to/from milliseconds as needed within the getter/setter functions?

Comment: Using milliseconds will give you the best date/time precision. You can also use seconds upon storing but then you loose the millisecond precision, having just second precision.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll take that over my epoch seconds.