# Spring Data Rest: Date serialize date as timestamp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring boot and spring data rest to build RESTful APIs. I want to date in json response format as timestamp. Currently, my response is:

```
{
  "firstName": "An",
  "lastName": "Nguyen",
  "createdDate": "2016-04-17T03:25:44.000+0000"
}
```

I expect it as:

```
{
  "firstName": "An",
  "lastName": "Nguyen",
  "createdDate": "1469346389"
}
```

How can I do that? What does need to be reconfigured?

My model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> implements UserDetails {

  @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "created_date")
  private Date createdDate = new Date();

  .....
}
```

My repository:

```
@Transactional
@RestResource(path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

    User findByUsername(@NotNull String username);

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The answer somewhat depends on what type `Date` is. Is it `Joda`, `java.time`, `java.util`, or something else? The answer is probably that you need to configure Jackson `SerializationFeature` but which one depends on the type of `Date`.

Comment: @JudgingNotJudging the type of `createDate` field is `java.util.Date`. My problem was solved by an answer that I accepted

Answer (score 5):

Hope this annotation can help you:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the default `ObjectMapper` used by Spring Data REST, such as:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringDataRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the date as a long. There's a post here that does something like that.

[Properly Utilizing Epoch Seconds with JPA in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329482/properly-utilizing-epoch-seconds-with-jpa-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think this is the best way and I'm looking for another solution for that.